# No inference when converting Tensorflow object detection SSD Mobiledet model to TFLite

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I have retrained a SSD MobileDet 320x320 for the edge TPU on TensorFlow 1 following this [guide](https://namburger.medium.com/deploy-your-own-ssdlite-mobiledet-object-detector-on-google-corals-edgetpu-using-tensorflow-s-f41f1e3360c8) using another dataset.

The training runs and completes smoothly with decent results. I have exported the TF1 inference graph like this:

```
!python3 /content/models/research/object_detection/export_inference_graph.py \
    --input_type=image_tensor \
    --pipeline_config_path=/content/pretrained_model/ssdlite_mobiledet_edgetpu_320x320_coco_2020_05_19/fp32/pipeline.config \
    --output_directory=/content/ssd_inference_graph \
    --trained_checkpoint_prefix=/content/train_2/model.ckpt-20000
```

I tested the inference on the exported graph and got good results:

[image: TF1 inference test]

I have then exported the SSD TFlite graph:

```
!python3 object_detection/export_tflite_ssd_graph.py \
  --pipeline_config_path=/content/drive/MyDrive/ssd_inference_graph/pipeline.config \
  --trained_checkpoint_prefix=/content/drive/MyDrive/ssd_inference_graph/train_2/model.ckpt-20000 \
  --output_directory=/content/output_model \
  --add_postprocessing_op=true
```

And converted to TensorFlow Lite:

```
!tflite_convert \
  --output_file="/content/drive/MyDrive/SSD_TF1_V3/output_model/ssdlite_mobiledet_dota_2.tflite" \
  --graph_def_file="/content/drive/MyDrive/SSD_TF1_V3/output_model/tflite_graph.pb" \
  --inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 \
  --input_arrays="normalized_input_image_tensor" \
  --output_arrays="TFLite_Detection_PostProcess,TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1,TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2,TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3" \
  --mean_values=128 \
  --std_dev_values=128 \
  --input_shapes=1,320,320,3 \
  --allow_custom_ops
```

I tried to test the converted TFlite model using this code:

```
import os
import re
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
%matplotlib inline

# Creates tflite interpreter
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter('/content/drive/MyDrive/ssd_inference_graph/output_model/ssdlite_mobiledet_dota.tflite')
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
interpreter.invoke() # warmup
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
width = input_details[0]['shape'][2]
height = input_details[0]['shape'][1]

def read_label_file(file_path):
  with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
  ret = {}
  for row_number, content in enumerate(lines):
    pair = re.split(r'[:\s]+', content.strip(), maxsplit=1)
    if len(pair) == 2 and pair[0].strip().isdigit():
      ret[int(pair[0])] = pair[1].strip()
    else:
      ret[row_number] = content.strip()
  return ret

def run_inference(interpreter, image):
  interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], image)
  interpreter.invoke()
  boxes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])[0]
  classes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[1]['index'])[0]
  scores = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[2]['index'])[0]
  num_detections = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[3]['index'])[0]
  return boxes, classes, scores

test_image_paths = [os.path.join('/content/test', 'image{}.png'.format(i)) for i in range(1, 6)]
for image_path in test_image_paths:
  print('Evaluating:', image_path)
  image = Image.open(image_path)
  image_width, image_height = image.size
  draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
  resized_image = image.resize((width, height))
  np_image = np.asarray(resized_image)
  input_tensor = np.expand_dims(np_image, axis=0)
  # Run inference
  boxes, classes, scores = run_inference(interpreter, input_tensor)
  # Draw results on image
  colors = {0:(128, 255, 102), 1:(102, 255, 255)}
  labels = {0:'plane', 1:'ship', 2:'storage-tank', 3: 'baseball-diamond', 4: 'tennis-court', 5: 'basketball-court', 6: 'ground-track-field', 7: 'harbor', 8: 'bridge',
            9: 'large-vehicle', 10: 'helicopter', 11: 'roundabout', 12: 'soccer-ball-field', 13: '14 swimming-pool'}
  for i in range(len(boxes)):
    if scores[i] > 7:
      ymin = int(max(1, (boxes[i][0] * image_height)))
      xmin = int(max(1, (boxes[i][1] * image_width)))
      ymax = int(min(image_height, (boxes[i][2] * image_height)))
      xmax = int(min(image_width, (boxes[i][3] * image_width)))
      draw.rectangle((xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax), width=7, outline=colors[int(classes[i])])
      draw.rectangle((xmin, ymin, xmax, ymin-10), fill=colors[int(classes[i])])
      text = labels[int(classes[i])] + ' ' + str(scores[i]*100) + '%'
      draw.text((xmin+2, ymin-10), text, fill=(0,0,0), width=2)
  display(image)
```

But there is no inference, it just returns the input image without any boxes or detection.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I see that you use mean,std =128 for converting into tflite.But I do not see this normalization when you load the images. Am I right?

Comment: You are right - I haven't normalized the images when loading them.

Comment: @Farmaker, how would I normalize the images when loading them?

Comment: I saw the repo and the author doesn't seem to use mean/std when loading the images, but they are using mean/std when converting to tflite. This is strange! So first of all you can run the colab from the top to bottom to see if you get boxes with tflite. If not try to ommit the mean/std parameters from tflite convert script.

Comment: With the dataset used in the repo example, I get the boxes after converting to tflite. I also tried converting my inference graph to tflite without mean/std parameters but got this error: ValueError: std_dev and mean must be defined when inference_input_type is QUANTIZED_UINT8.

Comment: So set mean = 0 and std = 1 and see what is the result.

Comment: Just tried it - still no boxes.

Comment: It is weird that it is working inside the colab notebook and not at your script. I have no other thing to help you. Just try it again taking scripts from the colab. Bye.